# Google plus button added by javascript -> Only showing up after page reload [GWT app]

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe, google-plus

I have a GWT Application and I use the "GWT Activities and Places" for Navigation, Browserhistory and so on. Now I try to incorporate the google plus button, so the user can recommend single specific articles. As you can see in the first screenshot, I have a google plus button in the footer as well. That one is directly included in the host page (the HTML-Page) and shows up on the first page load. The second one is part of the article widget and therefore added to the host page via javascript. This one doesn't show up on the first page load, but if I reload the page (see the second screenshot after pressing F5). Is there any solution to that problem?

I had the same problem for the facebook like button. I could solve that by switching from the HTML5 version to the iFrame version. Is there another version of the google plus button as well?

Here is my code. First I include the google plus script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en-US'
  };

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

This code adds the button:

```
<div class='g-plusone' data-annotation='inline' data-width='300' data-href='http://gwt-prime.appspot.com/fb/ArticleSection/4'></div>
```

**Screenshots:**

Fist load of the page -> Button is missing:

[image]

After reload of page -> Button shows up:

[image: liev]

**Example link**

To check out the page yourself, have a look here: [live example](http://gwt-prime.appspot.com/#!ArticleSection:4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling this jsni snippet once your site is fully rendered:

```
/**
 * Render any Google+ button inside of the container identified by containerId.
 */
static public native void go(String containerId) /*-{
    $wnd.gapi.plusone.go(containerId);
}-*/;
```